# How to pass ref from parent to child component in template

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, element-ui

I am using this component https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/popover

Issue related to triggering element (it is used to calculate where is popover located)

> For the triggering element, you can write it in two different ways: use the `slot="reference"` named slot, or use the `v-popover` directive and set it to Popover's ref.

Everything ok with default examples. But I am using [transparent wrapper](https://kamal.io/blog/transparent-vue-wrapper-components) for `el-popover` component like so.

```html
<script id="my-popover" type="x-template">
<el-popover
  ref="mypopover"
  transition="el-zoom-in-top"
  v-bind="$attrs"
  v-on="$listeners"
>
  <!-- Pass on all named slots -->
  <slot
    v-for="slot in Object.keys($slots)"
    :slot="slot"
    :name="slot"
  />
  <span> My popover </span>
</el-popover>
</script>
```

It works ok with `slot="reference"` named slot.

```html
<my-popover 
    placement="bottom"
    title="Title"
    width="200"
    trigger="manual"
    v-model="visible"
>
    <el-button
        slot="reference" 
        @click="visible = !visible"
    >
        Click me
    </el-button>
</my-popover>
```

But due to complex layout I need to use `v-popover` directive. Got no luck with wrapped component.

```html
<my-popover
    ref="popover"
    placement="right"
    title="Title2"
    width="200"
    trigger="manual"
    v-model="visible2"
>
</my-popover>
<el-button 
    v-popover:popover
    @click="visible2 = !visible2"
>
    Click me too
</el-button>
```

So I need somehow to pass in `v-popover` reference to `ref="mypopover"` from wrapped component. I.e. pass ref to child directly in template.

I've tried `v-popover:popover.$refs.mypopover` but that doesn't work.

Related codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rgRNZr

Click on button `Click me too` should show popup connected to that button.

Comment: Your codepen shows both working for me

Comment: @Dan `Click me too` shows pop up in wrong place. It is doesn't connected with button. Should be right after button.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the ref you want is the one that is on the el-popover but you are using the ref that is set on the my-popover component instead of the one you want.

This is kind of a wierd thing since that component wants a ref but it will be annoying to get one from the component inside your component.

I would put the button and popup with a slot in the same component.